# How to set maximum size of Room database

Tags: android-sqlite, android-room

I'm trying to set the maximum size of Room database. I found that I can set `maximumSize` in database `onCreate()` callback, but then when I'm checking this value in `onOpen()` callback it is not changed.

Here is my code:

```
val db = Room.databaseBuilder(
    appContext,
    MyDatabase::class.java,
    "name",
).addCallback(
    object : RoomDatabase.Callback() {
        override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            super.onCreate(db)
            db.maximumSize = 8796093014016
            Log.e("size in onCreate = ", db.maximumSize.toString())
        }

        override fun onOpen(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            super.onOpen(db)
            Log.e("size in onOpen = ", db.maximumSize.toString())
        }
    },
).build()
```

it prints:

```
size in onCreate = 8796093014016

size in onOpen = 4398046507008
```

It confuses me as I would expect it to print the following:

```
size in onCreate = 8796093014016

size in onOpen = 8796093014016
```

Any ideas what is wrong with this approach of changing room database size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do you know how to configure a database not to accept files above some limit?

First some understanding of what the *"file(s)"* consists off is likely very important.

In short by default Room will use WAL (Write Ahead Logging) rather than Journal mode.

In WAL mode the Database may consist of 3 files:-

1. The Core database file.
2. The WAL file (the database file suffixed with **-wal**). Importantly if this exists, it should be considered as part of the database. That is it contains data that is yet to be applied to the core database file.
3. The SHM file (the database file suffixed with **-shm**). This isn't as important, it can be considered as a wal file for the wal file.

In Journal mode the Database will consist of 2 files:-

1. The Core database file.
2. The -journal file. This is a record/log of changes made and can be used to undo/rollback changes (as such it's size does not affect the core database file size)

So really the file size should be the Core database's file size plus the size of the -wal file and the -shm file.

However, SQLite stores data in blocks of a set size called pages (by default 4k in size). A page may or may not be full and the data held by pages may be combined or reduced by housekeeping (e.g. a `VACUUM`).

There is not a means to restrict the file size directly, to SQLite it is just a file. However the number of pages can be restricted by using the [`max_page_count` PRAGMA](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_max_page_count).

- see the demo below

So there are two ways to implement a restriction you can either check the file size and then implement some handling or you can rely upon the page count in which case you would have to then handle the ensuing SQLITE_FULL exception that would result if a page were required that would exceed the page count.

The following demonstrates retrieving the file size and setting the maximum page count:-

The `@Database` annotated class **TheDatabase** :-

```
@Database(entities = [AuthorEntity::class,BookEntity::class,AuthorBookCrossRef::class,InfoTable::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class TheDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getAllDAOs(): AllDAOs

    fun getOverSizeIndicator(): Boolean {
        return TheDatabase.isDatabaseOversize(this, maxsize)
    }
    fun getFileSize(): Long {
        return TheDatabase.getDatabaseFileSize(this.openHelper.writableDatabase.path!!)
    }
    fun getPageSize(): Long {
        return TheDatabase.getPageSize(this)
    }
    fun getPageCount(): Long {
        return TheDatabase.getPageCount(this)
    }

    companion object {
        val maxsize = /*4398046507008 + 1024*/ 8796093014016
        var overSize = false
        var instance: TheDatabase?=null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): TheDatabase {
            if (instance==null) {
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase::class.java,"the_database.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .addCallback(object : RoomDatabase.Callback(){
                        override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                            super.onCreate(db)
                            logMMAPSize(db,"CRTS")
                            db.setMaximumSize(maxsize)
                            logMMAPSize(db,"CRTE")
                            Log.d("PGCOUNT","PAGE COUNT is ${getPageCount(db)} MAXPAGECOUNT is ${getMaxPageCount(db)}")
                            setMaxPageCount(db, getPageCount(db)+100)
                            Log.d("PGCOUNT","PAGE COUNT is ${getPageCount(db)} MAXPAGECOUNT is ${getMaxPageCount(db)}")
                        }

                        override fun onOpen(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                            super.onOpen(db)
                            logMMAPSize(db,"OPNS")
                            if (db.maximumSize < maxsize) {
                                db.setMaximumSize(maxsize)
                            }
                            logMMAPSize(db,"OPNE")
                            overSize = isDatabaseOversize(db, maxsize)
                        }
                    })
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as TheDatabase
        }

        fun logMMAPSize(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase, tagSuffix: String) {
            Log.d("MMAPSize_$tagSuffix","MMAPSize is ${db.maximumSize}")

        }
        fun getDatabaseFileSize(databasePath: String): Long {
            var size = File(databasePath).totalSpace
            if (File("$databasePath-shm").exists()) {
                size += File("$databasePath-shm").totalSpace
            }
            if (File("$databasePath-wal").exists()) {
                size += File("$databasePath-wal").totalSpace
            }
            return size
        }
        private fun isDatabaseOversize(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase, maxSize: Long): Boolean {
            val dbPath = db.path ?: return false
            return getDatabaseFileSize(dbPath) >= maxSize
        }
        fun isDatabaseOversize(db: TheDatabase, maxSize: Long): Boolean {
            return isDatabaseOversize(db.openHelper.writableDatabase,maxSize)
        }
        private fun getPageSize(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase): Long {
            var rv: Long = 0
            val csr = db.query("SELECT * FROM pragma_page_size")
            if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
                rv = csr.getLong(0)
            }
            csr.close()
            return rv
        }
        fun getPageSize(db: TheDatabase): Long {
            return getPageSize(db.openHelper.writableDatabase)
        }
        private fun getPageCount(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase): Long {
            var rv: Long = 0
            val csr = db.query("SELECT * FROM pragma_page_count")
            if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
                rv = csr.getLong(0)
            }
            csr.close()
            return rv
        }
        fun getPageCount(db: TheDatabase): Long {
            return getPageCount(db.openHelper.writableDatabase)
        }

        private fun getMaxPageCount(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase): Long {
            var rv: Long = 0
            val csr = db.query("SELECT * FROM pragma_max_page_count")
            if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
                rv = csr.getLong(0)
            }
            csr.close()
            return rv;
        }
        fun getMaxPageCount(db: TheDatabase): Long {
            return getMaxPageCount(db.openHelper.writableDatabase)
        }

        fun setMaxPageCount(db: TheDatabase,maxPageCount: Long): Long {
            return setMaxPageCount(db.openHelper.writableDatabase,maxPageCount)
        }
        private fun setMaxPageCount(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase, maxPageCount: Long): Long {
            var rv: Long = 0
            val csr = db.query("PRAGMA max_page_count=${maxPageCount}")
            rv = if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
                csr.getLong(0)
            } else {
                getMaxPageCount(db)
            }
            csr.close()
            return rv
        }
    }
}
```

The `@Dao` annotated **AllDAOs** interface includes:-

```
@Query("")
fun logMMAPSize(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase,tagSuffix: String) {
    TheDatabase.logMMAPSize(db,tagSuffix)
}
```

The Activity code includes :-

```
    db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
    dao = db.getAllDAOs()
    dao.logMMAPSize(db.openHelper.writableDatabase,"AFTOPN")
    dao.deleteAllInfoTableRows()
    dao.insert(InfoTable(createdDate = "2023-01-01", starred = "starred001", text = "ZZZZ"))
    dao.insert(InfoTable(createdDate = "2022-01-01", starred = "starred009", text = "YYYY"))
    dao.insert(InfoTable(createdDate = "2022-02-01", starred = "starred008", text = "XXXX"))
    dao.insert(InfoTable(createdDate = "2022-03-01", starred = "starred007", text = "WWWW"))
    dao.logMMAPSize(db.openHelper.writableDatabase,"AFTCHG")

    Log.d("DB_OVERSIZE","The indicator that the database files are oversize is ${db.getOverSizeIndicator()}")
    Log.d("DB_FILESIZE","Total file size is ${db.getFileSize()} " +
            "PageSize is ${db.getPageSize()} " +
            "PageCount is ${db.getPageCount()} " +
            "Size according to Pages = ${db.getPageSize() * db.getPageCount()} " +
            "MaxPageCount = ${TheDatabase.getMaxPageCount(db)}")
    TheDatabase.setMaxPageCount(db,TheDatabase.getPageCount(db))
    Log.d("DB_FILESIZE","Total file size is ${db.getFileSize()} " +
            "PageSize is ${db.getPageSize()} " +
            "PageCount is ${db.getPageCount()} " +
            "Size according to Pages = ${db.getPageSize() * db.getPageCount()} " +
            "MaxPageCount = ${TheDatabase.getMaxPageCount(db)}")


    dao.insert(InfoTable(createdDate = "2023-01-01", starred = "starred001", text = "ZZZZ"))
    dao.insert(InfoTable(createdDate = "2022-01-01", starred = "starred009", text = "YYYY"))
    dao.insert(InfoTable(createdDate = "2022-02-01", starred = "starred008", text = "XXXX"))
    dao.insert(InfoTable(createdDate = "2022-03-01", starred = "starred007", text = "WWWW"))
```

**Result**

When run from a fresh install:-

```
2023-05-24 08:24:23.614 D/MMAPSize_CRTS: MMAPSize is 4398046507008
2023-05-24 08:24:23.617 D/MMAPSize_CRTE: MMAPSize is 8796093014016

2023-05-24 08:24:23.618 D/PGCOUNT: PAGE COUNT is 11 MAXPAGECOUNT is 2147483646
2023-05-24 08:24:23.623 D/PGCOUNT: PAGE COUNT is 11 MAXPAGECOUNT is 111

2023-05-24 08:24:23.633 D/MMAPSize_OPNS: MMAPSize is 4398046507008
2023-05-24 08:24:23.636 D/MMAPSize_OPNE: MMAPSize is 8796093014016
2023-05-24 08:24:23.638 D/MMAPSize_AFTOPN: MMAPSize is 8796093014016
2023-05-24 08:24:23.664 D/MMAPSize_AFTCHG: MMAPSize is 8796093014016

2023-05-24 08:24:23.664 D/DB_OVERSIZE: The indicator that the database files are oversize is false
2023-05-24 08:24:23.671 D/DB_FILESIZE: Total file size is 2437595136 PageSize is 4096 PageCount is 11 Size according to Pages = 45056 MaxPageCount = 2147483646
2023-05-24 08:24:23.683 D/DB_FILESIZE: Total file size is 2437595136 PageSize is 4096 PageCount is 11 Size according to Pages = 45056 MaxPageCount = 11
```

- OVERSIZE is false as maxsize (8796093014016) was used as the test/comparison value.
- as can be seen the max page count was initially reduced from 2147483646 to 111 (in the onCreate callback)
- later, in the activity processing, the maxpage count has been reduced from 2147483646 ***(onCreate's setting has been ignored/overwritten)*** to 11

In a subsequent run (the database exists) then the log includes:-

```
2023-05-24 08:39:33.457 26881-26881/a.a.so76273561fkey D/MMAPSize_OPNS: MMAPSize is 4398046507008
2023-05-24 08:39:33.459 26881-26881/a.a.so76273561fkey D/MMAPSize_OPNE: MMAPSize is 8796093014016
2023-05-24 08:39:33.461 26881-26881/a.a.so76273561fkey D/MMAPSize_AFTOPN: MMAPSize is 8796093014016
2023-05-24 08:39:33.482 26881-26881/a.a.so76273561fkey D/MMAPSize_AFTCHG: MMAPSize is 8796093014016

2023-05-24 08:39:33.483 26881-26881/a.a.so76273561fkey D/DB_OVERSIZE: The indicator that the database files are oversize is false
2023-05-24 08:39:33.489 26881-26881/a.a.so76273561fkey D/DB_FILESIZE: Total file size is 2437595136 PageSize is 4096 PageCount is 11 Size according to Pages = 45056 MaxPageCount = 2147483646
2023-05-24 08:39:33.498 26881-26881/a.a.so76273561fkey D/DB_FILESIZE: Total file size is 2437595136 PageSize is 4096 PageCount is 11 Size according to Pages = 45056 MaxPageCount = 11
```

- Note that the default max page count was reinstated to 2147483646 (so like for maximumSize it should be applied in the onOpen callback)

Answer (score 0):

> How to set maximum size of Room database

**Set(increase) the size in the `onOpen` callback not the `onCreate` callback.**

- irrespective of the issue (guess), `onCreate` will only run once for the lifetime of the database. The size change is only in affect for the connection and thus will never be applied except when `onCreate` is called.

> Any ideas what is wrong with this approach of changing room database size?

As above and also in regard to your findings:-

My **guess**, is that when the onCreate callback is called that it is part of a transaction and thus is not undertaken according to:-

> *[The size of the memory-mapped I/O region cannot be changed while the memory-mapped I/O region is in active use](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_mmap_size)*

- the assumption is that *database size* is referring to the MMAP_SIZE. You may wish to refer to [Memory-Mapped I/O](https://www.sqlite.org/mmap.html) as I believe that Room's use of ***database size*** may not be what would typically be considered as the database size (i.e. I don't believe that it refers to the file size)

Perhaps consider the following simple extension of your testing.

First a function in the/an `@Dao` annotated interface. The function writes the size to the log and expects an **SQLiteSupportDatabase** is passed and also a String so the output to the log can easily be ascertained if the String is thoughtfully set:-

```
@Query("")
fun logMMAPSize(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase,tagSuffix: String) {
    TheDatabase.logMMAPSize(db,tagSuffix)
}
```

An amended callBack as per:-

```
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .addCallback(object : RoomDatabase.Callback(){
                    override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                        super.onCreate(db)
                        logMMAPSize(db,"CRTS")
                        db.setMaximumSize(maxsize)
                        logMMAPSize(db,"CRTE")
                    }

                    override fun onOpen(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                        super.onOpen(db)
                        logMMAPSize(db,"OPNS")
                        if (db.maximumSize < maxsize) {
                            db.setMaximumSize(maxsize)
                        }
                        logMMAPSize(db,"OPNE")
                    }
                })
```

- of course, considering the findings of the simple extension, the increased size can be set directly rather than testing *(the test was used for some more extensive testing)*.

And maxsize as `val maxsize = /*4398046507008 + 1024*/ 8796093014016`

Finally within an activity (note that `.allowMainThreadQueries` has been used for ease of demonstration):-

```
    db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
    dao = db.getAllDAOs()
    dao.logMMAPSize(db.openHelper.writableDatabase,"AFTOPN")
    dao.deleteAllInfoTableRows()
    dao.insert(InfoTable(createdDate = "2023-01-01", starred = "starred001", text = "ZZZZ"))
    dao.insert(InfoTable(createdDate = "2022-01-01", starred = "starred009", text = "YYYY"))
    dao.insert(InfoTable(createdDate = "2022-02-01", starred = "starred008", text = "XXXX"))
    dao.insert(InfoTable(createdDate = "2022-03-01", starred = "starred007", text = "WWWW"))
    dao.logMMAPSize(db.openHelper.writableDatabase,"AFTCHG")
```

noting that:-

- getting the SupportSQLiteDatabase will create/open the database and thus invoke the respective callbacks
- after the opening is handled a subsequent retrieval of the size
- then after actually amending data a further retrieval of the size is invoked.

When run for a new install then:-

```
2023-05-23 12:13:24.278 D/MMAPSize_CRTS: MMAPSize is 4398046507008
2023-05-23 12:13:24.280 D/MMAPSize_CRTE: MMAPSize is 8796093014016

2023-05-23 12:13:24.290 D/MMAPSize_OPNS: MMAPSize is 4398046507008
2023-05-23 12:13:24.292 D/MMAPSize_OPNE: MMAPSize is 8796093014016

2023-05-23 12:13:24.296 D/MMAPSize_AFTOPN: MMAPSize is 8796093014016
2023-05-23 12:13:24.321 D/MMAPSize_AFTCHG: MMAPSize is 8796093014016
```

- as can be seen the increased size still remains after the onOpen callback.